# Pythonic way to iterate through a range starting at 1

Tags: python, loops

Currently if I want to iterate **`1`** through **`n`** I would likely use the following method:

```
for _ in range(1, n+1):
    print(_)
```

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this without having to reference **`n + 1`** ?

It seems odd that if I want to iterate a range ordinally starting at 1, which is not uncommon, that I have to specify the increase by one twice:

1. With the `1` at the start of the range.
2. With the `+ 1` at the end of the range.

Comment: Why do you think this is a "dirty" way?

Comment: `n+1` evaluates once, so this is not a `dirty` way. As an option, if you don't like `n+1` as the `range` parameter, evaluate it earlier and save the result to a variable, then use this variable in the `range` call.

Comment: *I have to specify the increase by one twice*  You're not doing this even once. You're specifying the *start* (`1`) and the *end* (`n+1`) of the range. You're not specifying an increase/increment at all

Comment: I want to iterate n times, but have to modify the reference to n in order to establish the iteration.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `n` is improperly assigned. If you correct the assignment of `n` (wherever that is, elsewhere in your code) then you can just do `for i in range(1,n):` but you may need to `n+=1` because a range is indexed from `0`, so `range(2) == [0,1]`, etc.

Comment: `n` here is *not* the "number of iterations", it's the upper bound of your `range`.

Comment: The range in my example is just a means of establishing the iteration. What I'm asking is if there is an alternative where I can establish the same loop without have to add to ***n***.

Comment: [This is how ranges work...](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) If you are *not* expecting to use `n` as the upper bound of the range (equivalent to `len(range(n))` then your expectations are simply mistaken.

Comment: I'm not necessarily expecting to use ranges at all.

Comment: You can do it with a `while` loop, but that would be silly because then you'd have to a) initially assign `1` and b) increment at *each* iteration. `i=1: while i <=10: print i: i+=1`  The range is obviously more efficient and appropriate for this sort of iteration.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`range(1, n+1)` is not considered duplication, but I can see that this might become a hassle if you were going to change `1` to another number.

This removes the duplication using a generator:

```
for _ in (number+1 for number in range(5)):
    print(_)
```

Comment: Nice answer to the question but have we really moved forward from `range(1, n+1)`

Comment: I wouldn't say so. I just had this cool generator idea which seemed really pythonic and wanted to share it.

Answer (score 43):

From the documentation:

```
range([start], stop[, step])
```

The start defaults to 0, the step can be whatever you want, except 0 and stop is your upper bound, it is not the number of iterations. So declare n to be whatever your upper bound is correctly and you will not have to add 1 to it.

e.g.

```
>>> for i in range(1, 7, 1): print(i)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
>>> for i in range(1, 7, 2): print(i)
... 
1
3
5
```

A nice feature, is that it works in reverse as well.

```
>>> for i in range(7, 0, -1): print(i)
... 
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

If you aren't using it as an index but for something that can have positive or negative values, it still comes in handy:

```
>>> for i in range(2, -3, -1): print(i)
... 
2
1
0
-1
-2
>>> for i in range(-2, 3, 1): print(i)
... 
-2
-1
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 4):

`range(1, n+1)` is common way to do it, but if you don't like it, you can create your function:

```
def numbers(first_number, last_number, step=1):
    return range(first_number, last_number+1, step)

for _ in numbers(1, 5):
    print(_)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(n):
    print(i+1)
```

This will output:

```
1 
2
...
n
```

Comment: This doesn't mean much cleaner, as I would have to use +1 whenever I want to reference loop count. Rather than using +1 once when defining the loop I may have to use it multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Not a general answer, but for *very* small ranges (say, up to five), I find it much more readable to spell them out in a literal:

```
for _ in [1,2,3]:
    print _
```

That's true even if it does start from zero.