# How to write a python loop

Tags: python

I have 2 tables in the database:

```
class User(db.Model): 
  id = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(80))
  ex_1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
  ex_2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
  .....
  ex_10 = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Ex(db.Model): #задания
  id = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(80))
  text = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

If the user completed the task, then in the field ex_1, for example, the value is 1, if not completed, then 0.

How to check the tasks of the user from the beginning and send him the first failed task? Tasks also 10 and id from 1 to 10 How to implement such a cycle? Tell me please!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to iterate through a range starting at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282444/pythonic-way-to-iterate-through-a-range-starting-at-1)

Answer (score 0):

Use signal

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def after_update_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    # 'target' is the update object
    if not target.ex_1:
        send_fail_task(target.id)
    # if task also 10 or 1 to 10, Add a conditional statement, ps:
    if target.ex_1.id == 10:
        do_something()

event.listen(User, 'after_update', after_update_listener)
```